# How to put icon on Sliding Menu (android)

Tags: android

```
<string name="app_name">SlidingMenuExample</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="lorem_ipsum">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, modo. Fusce mauris purus, aliquet spor det.</string>

<array name="nav_drawer_icons">
    <item>@drawable/menu</item>
    <item>@drawable/table</item>
    <item>@drawable/settings</item>
</array>
```

How to put this icons on my Sliding Menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

please refer this, This is one of the best sliding menu implementation library. U can also customize sliding menu according your project requirements.